# Convert character YYYY-MM-00 into date YYYY-MM in R

Tags: r, excel, character, date-conversion

I imported Excel data into R and I have a problem to convert dates.
In R, my data are character and look like :

date<-c('1971-02-00 00:00:00', '1979-06-00 00:00:00')

I would like to convert character into date (MM/YYYY) but the '00' value used for days poses a problem and 'NA' are returned systematically.
It works when I manually replace '00' with '01' and then use as.yearmon, ymd and format. But I have lots of dates to change and I don't know how to change all my '00' into '01' in R.

```
# data exemple
date1<-c('1971-02-00 00:00:00', '1979-06-00 00:00:00')

# removing time -> doesn't work because of the '00' day
date1c<-format(strptime(date1, format = "%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y/%m/%d")
date1c<-format(strptime(date1, format = '%Y-%m'), '%Y/%m')

# trying to convert character into date -> doesn't work either
date1c<-ymd(date1)
date1c<-strptime(date1, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
date1c<-as.Date(date1, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
date1c<as.yearmon(date1, format='%Y%m')

# everything works if days are '01'
date2<-c('1971-02-01 00:00:00', '1979-06-01 00:00:00')
date2c<-as.yearmon(ymd(format(strptime(date2, format = "%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y/%m/%d")))
date2c
```

If you have an idea to do it or an another idea to solve my problem, I would be thankful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possibility could be:

```
as.Date(paste0(substr(date1, 1, 9), "1"), format = "%Y-%m-%d")

[1] "1971-02-01" "1979-06-01"
```

Here it extracts the first nine characters, pastes it together with `1` and then converts it into a date object.

Answer (score 1):

Use `gsub` to replace `-00` with `-01`.

```
date1<-c('1971-02-01 00:00:00', '1979-06-01 00:00:00')
date1 <- gsub("-00", "-01", date1)

date1c <-format(strptime(date1, format = "%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y/%m/%d")

> date1c
[1] "1971/02/01" "1979/06/01"
```

Answer (score 0):

These alternatives each accept a vector input and produce a vector as output.

### Date output

These all will accept a vector as input and produce a `Date` vector as the output.

```
# 1. replace first occurrence of '00 ' with '01 ' and then convert to Date

as.Date(sub("00 ", "01 ", date1))
## [1] "1971-02-01" "1979-06-01"

# 2. convert to yearmon class and then to Date

library(zoo)
as.Date(as.yearmon(date1, "%Y-%m"))
## [1] "1971-02-01" "1979-06-01"

# 3. insert a 1 and then convert to Date

as.Date(paste(1, date1), "%d %Y-%m")
## [1] "1971-02-01" "1979-06-01"
```

### yearmon output

Note that if you really are trying to represent just months and years then `yearmon` class directly represents such objects without the kludge of using an unused day of the month.  Such objects are internally represented as a year plus a fraction of a year, i.e. year + 0 for January, year + 1/12 for February, etc. They display in a meaningful way, they sort in the expected manner and can be manipulated, e.g. take the difference between two such objects or add 1/12 to get the next month, etc.  As with the others it takes a vector in and produces a vector out.

```
library(zoo)
as.yearmon(date1, "%Y-%m")
## [1] "Feb 1971" "Jun 1979"
```

### character output

If you want `character` output rather than `Date` or `yearmon` output then these variations work and again accept a vector as input and produce a vector as output:

```
# 1. replace -00 and everything after that with a string having 0 characters

sub("-00.*", "", date1)
## [1] "1971-02" "1979-06"

# 2. convert to yearmon and then format that

library(zoo)
format(as.yearmon(date1, "%Y-%m"), "%Y-%m")
## [1] "1971-02" "1979-06"

# 3. convert to Date class and then format that

format(as.Date(paste(1, date1), "%d %Y-%m"), "%Y-%m")
## [1] "1971-02" "1979-06"

# 4. pick off the first 7 characters

substring(date1, 1, 7)
## [1] "1971-02" "1979-06"
```